# x86 Assembly (Linux) stdin read syscall returning 1 with no data input

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, stdin

When I compare $0 against %eax for error checking, and enter no input when prompted, the error message does not display. However, when I compare $1 against %eax and enter no input, the error message displays. I'm aware that a read syscall returns the amount of bytes read into %eax, although I'm unsure as to why it returns a byte was read when no input is given, the man pages also don't give me any indication to why this is the case. Is stdin input null-terminated or is it something else?

```
 movl $3, %eax
 movl $0, %ebx
 movl $BUFFER, %ecx
 movl $BUFFER_SIZE, %edx
 int  $0x80

 cmpl $0, %eax
 jle  input_error
```

If cmpl $0 is changed to cmpl $1, and no input is given, it jumps to input_error, with cmpl $0 program flow proceeds when no input is given.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Edited to include code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call sys_read with these parameters and to expect that there will be no input.

sys_read is blocking call. So, it will block until some input appears. In your case, IMO, you press ENTER and in this case, sys_read returns with 1 byte read in the buffer - LF, ascii code 0Ah and eax=1.

P.S. It is not my job, but better use FASM or at least NASM. This way you will get much more help in your ASM programming. GAS has really terrible syntax. :)